# Float number addition is not right

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point

So I'm trying do detect a particular circle in an image, I'm using an openCV function, I tried tweaking the parameters but I'm not happy.

So I'm going to bruteforce the 4 parameters.

To do this I wrote this piece of code wich generates a list containing all the values to try on one parameter :

```
def paramlistgene(increment, fromvalue, tovalue):
    paramlist = [fromvalue]
    while paramlist[-1] < tovalue:
        paramlist.append(paramlist[-1] + increment)
    return paramlist
```

for example paramlistgene(0.1, 0.1, 20) should generate :

```
[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, ..., 20]
```

but it generates this :

```
[0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7999999999999999, 0.8999999999999999, 0.9999999999999999, 1.0999999999999999, 1.2, ...]
```

Why does this happens?

I tried print 0.1+0.1+0.1 and it does print 0.3.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like a problem with precision error propagation.

Comment: try `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` and you get `False` . `float` can't keep all real values so it keeps approximations. Sometimes it displays full value and sometimes it displays rounded value. See `print("{:0.54f}".format(0.3))` and `print("{:0.54f}".format(0.1+0.2))`

Comment: oh well, I had no idea about this, I could have made such monstruous bugs!